# Extracting tarball C# using WinSCP .NET Assembly

Tags: c#, tar, scp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using WinSCP **.NET** Assembly in **C#** to transfer a tarball and extracting it.

My code works and I managed to copy the files. But my problem starts, when I try to extract them using `session.ExecuteCommand`. Nothing happens.

Trying to debug it I've added:

```
session.ExecuteCommand("touch /<path>/myfile.txt");
```

right after:

```
session.ExecuteCommand("tar -xzf /<path>/mytarball.tar.gz");
```

and the file is created, so the command and permission is not the problem and using:

```
result.Check();
string output = result.Output;
```

Shows that the files are extracted.

I'm using **SCP** protocol and not **SFTP**

Any suggesting ?

Br,
Idan

Comment: Can you show us the full upload/extract code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you assume that the command will extract the files to `/<path>`.

It won't. It extracts them to the current working directory (what is probably `/home/user`).

Use `-C` (or `--directory=`) switch to specify the output directory:

```
session.ExecuteCommand("tar -xzf /<path>/mytarball.tar.gz -C /<path>");
```

Comment: Thanks ! used the -C flag